# How to add lights to an existing pendant light fixture?

Tags: wiring, lighting, switch, light-fixture

I’m making string lights to add to a pendant light.  I want the lights I’m adding to be wired to the same wires / switch as the pendant light.  Can this be done & if so, how?

Also, the string lights I’m making will only have 3 candelabra bulbs.  How do I terminate the beginning of the wire (not the end attached to the pendant light)?

Comment: Don’t do it. You’ll loose your UL listing.

Comment: One thing many people forget about is track lighting. Place a track section at the box that feeds the pendant then use track fittings for other lights.